# How to use url formatter with integer

Tags: users, urls, user-access, id, content-restriction

I have this below code to prevent users from deleting the quizzes.

```
    if( 
    in_array( $pagenow, array('admin.php') ) &&
    ( $_GET['page'] == 'wpProQuiz' && $_GET['action'] == 'delete' && $_GET['id'] == '1' ) 
) {
    // Now check the current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $user->user_login == 'remo' ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

The code only for 1 quiz (see `$_GET['id'] == '1'`). But I have 40 quizzes. I learned that I could reuse this code without repeating 40 times using URL formatter.

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, very simple logic. Don't specify any id number.